# How to map c# linq Where Any to mongodb query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

C# MongoDbDriver throws unssuported filter exception when I try execute expression 
`collection.FindAsync(x=> inputCollection.Any(elem=> x.Prop1 <= elem && x.Prop2 >= elem))`

> Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.Int64[]).Where(((Convert({document}{Prop1 }, Int64) <= {document}) AndAlso (Convert({document}{Prop2}, Int64) >= {document})))).\r\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)\r\n

How to map it to MongoDb filters ?

Comment: Please provide the code context and the exception message, otherwise no one could locate the problem.

Comment: You are attempting to query a collection within a query to another collection, which is probably not supported. Try using linq join expressions instead.

Comment: @Alsein Could you provide any example of this ? inputCollection comes from user input.

Comment: Try this `(from a in collection.AsQueryable() from b in inputCollection.AsQueryable() where a.Prop1 <= b && a.Prop2 >= b select a).First()` I am not sure if it would work because I don't have an environment to test it.